# Passport.js verification always fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

My passport middleware is not working. When I call passport.authenticate() on a route to confirm the user is authenticated, I am redirected to the failure page. The login route however works as expected, and I am redirected successfully to the correct page, where the failure middleware redirect is called and I am sent back to the login page.

I have a Passport strategy like so:

```
module.exports = function(){ 
  var passport = require('passport');
  var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  var User = require('../models/user');
  // used to serialize the user for the session
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // used to deserialize the user
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: "email",
    passwordField: "password"
  }, function(email, password, done){
    User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        console.log('unknown user');
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Email not recognised, please try again'});  
      } 
      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          console.log('Invalid password');
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Password not recognised, please try again' });
        }
      });
    });
  }));
};
```

Logging in is fine using:

```
router.post('/user/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: '/clients',
    failureRedirect: '/user/login', 
    failureFlash: true
  }
));
```

My '/clients' route is like so, where the authentication fails and redirects incorrectly back to the login page:

```
router.get('/clients', 
  passport.authenticate("local", { 
    failureRedirect: "/user/login",
    failureFlash: "not verified" 
  }), function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.client = null;
  Client.find({})
    .select("name")
    .select("_id") 
    .exec(function(err, clients){
      res.render('client/views/clients', { 
        title: 'Clients',
        clients: clients 
      });
  });  
});
```

Server passport initialization like so:

```
//passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
require("./user/services/passport")(passport);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, show entire server file.

Comment: When you log out `email` and `password` inside your local strategy, do they exist?

Answer (score 0):

As you have used failureRedirect: '/user/login' . It will redirect you to the login page. If you want to redirect it to someother page change the failureRedirect value to that corresponding route.